# read write communication pySerial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

Hello I have trouble with read/write from or to device. I wanted to make a serial connection via rs 485 (half-duplex) . When I call read and write functions they didnt receive a data. Anyone know what I do wrong?

```
def Transmission(ser,data):
    if ser.isOpen():
        try:
            print(data)
            ser.flushInput()
            ser.flushOutput()
            ser.rtscts = True
            ser.write(data)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            numOfLines = 0
            print("write: " + data)
            while True:
                response = ser.readline()
                print("read data: " + response)
                ser.rtscts = False 
                numOfLines = numOfLines + 1
            if(numOfLines >= 5):
                ser.close()
        except Exception, e1:
            print "error communicating...: " + str(e1)
    else:
        print "cannot open serial port "
    return response
```

Terminal didnt show receiving data:

```
powah
write: powah
read data:
read data:
read data:
read data:
read data:
```

I tried to write with read in the loop (with changing `ser.rtscts`). How to fix that problem? Thank You

Comment: How do you know the device receives the data you sent to it?

Comment: I don't said that device received data. When I call read, the device didnt show received data

Comment: Have you tried reading [this](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.rs485.RS485Settings)

Comment: @F.Leone I will try with this, thank You

Comment: @F.Leone do u know how to make read from that link? I tried to make with that example but it isn't working...